# Error resolving cabal dependencies on Travis-CI

Tags: haskell, cabal, travis-ci, cabal-install, hakyll

I'm trying to build my Hakyll site using Travis-CI. However, before I even get that far, I have a dependencies error when trying to install Hakyll as a dependency.

I can build Hakyll locally on my machine with no problems. What might be causing the dependency error, and how can it be resolved? Is there a way to resolve it without actually hard-coding each dependency version?

Here's the output that comes from TravisCI.

```
travis_fold:end:git.5
$ export PATH=/usr/local/ghc/$(ghc_find 7.6)/bin/:$PATH
travis_fold:start:cabal
$ cabal update
Config file path source is default config file.
Config file /home/travis/.cabal/config not found.
Writing default configuration to /home/travis/.cabal/config
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
travis_fold:end:cabal
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1 of the Cabal library 
travis_fold:start:before_install.1
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install
travis_fold:end:before_install.1
travis_fold:start:before_install.2
$ cabal install hakyll pandoc
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: hakyll-4.5.3.0 (user goal)
trying: base-4.6.0.1/installed-8aa... (dependency of hakyll-4.5.3.0)
trying: hakyll-4.5.3.0:+checkexternal
trying: http-conduit-2.1.2.3 (dependency of hakyll-4.5.3.0:+checkexternal)
trying: http-client-0.3.3.2 (dependency of http-conduit-2.1.2.3)
trying: exceptions-0.6.1 (dependency of http-client-0.3.3.2)
trying: transformers-0.4.1.0 (dependency of http-conduit-2.1.2.3)
next goal: mtl (dependency of hakyll-4.5.3.0)
rejecting: mtl-2.2.1, 2.2.0.1, 2.2 (conflict: hakyll => mtl>=1 && <2.2)
rejecting: mtl-2.1.3.1, 2.1.2 (conflict: transformers==0.4.1.0, mtl =>
transformers==0.3.*)
rejecting: mtl-2.1.1, 2.1 (conflict: base==4.6.0.1/installed-8aa..., mtl =>
base<4.6)
rejecting: mtl-2.0.1.1 (conflict: transformers==0.4.1.0, mtl =>
transformers==0.2.*)
rejecting: mtl-2.0.1.0, 2.0.0.0 (conflict: base==4.6.0.1/installed-8aa..., mtl
=> base<4.6)
rejecting: mtl-1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.0, 1.1.0.2, 1.1.0.1, 1.1.0.0, 1.0 (conflict:
exceptions => mtl>=2.0 && <2.3)
Backjump limit reached (change with --max-backjumps).

[31;1mThe command "cabal install hakyll pandoc" failed and exited with 1 during .[0m

Your build has been stopped.
```

If there's any other output that would be useful, let me know and I can provide it.

Comment: Not a huge fan of the edit, as the error seems to be specific to Travis-CI and this site encourages informative titles.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit as I agree it made the question worse.

Comment: Do you have control over how cabal install is run on travis-ci? Could you run it with --max-backjumps=-1 ? If you need to add constraints I'd start by choosing a specific hakyll version that you know works locally with the same GHC as travis-ci is using.

Comment: Yeah, the travis-CI config file is basically like a bash script that gets run. I'll try with -1 backjump and see what we get, I'm suspicious that either their configuration changed, or isn't consistent across servers, since this problem didn't exist yesterday but has only started today.

Comment: Interesting, it worked. Maybe their cabal config had max backjumps set really low... it took a while though, around 4 minutes (Which isn't terrible relative to Travis-CI's normal speed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to try if you get `Backjump limit reached` from cabal-install is to try again with the option `--max-backjumps=-1` which means "search exhaustively", though if it then ends up taking tens of minutes you'd need to interrupt it or rely on the Travis-CI timeout. You can also use 500 or 1000 rather than -1 for a large but limited search - the default is 200.

If that doesn't work then try to pick out specific projects to constrain to a specific version with the option `--constraint 'foo==0.1.0.0`, preferably one that you actually know should be installable with the same GHC version.

In this particular case, the following two lines suggest that `hakyll` itself was at the root of the problem:

```
rejecting: mtl-2.2.1, 2.2.0.1, 2.2 (conflict: hakyll => mtl>=1 && <2.2)
rejecting: mtl-2.1.1, 2.1 (conflict: base==4.6.0.1/installed..., mtl => base<4.6)
```

In other words, `base`, which is tied to the GHC version, seems to require `mtl>=2.2` (or perhaps less than `2.1` but I suspect that wouldn't have worked either). `hakyll` was requiring `mtl<2.2`, so there seemed to be a fundamental conflict implying that this version of `hakyll` wouldn't work this version of `base`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this answer is worthwhile or the question should just be closed as either being unlikely to help future readers or a duplicate, but I searched for questions about cabal-install that mention `--max-backjumps` and didn't find any, so perhaps some general guidance on handling the problem is useful.